# Js работает нормально из папки на пк, но не работает как раcширение chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, chrome-extension

При нажатии на кнопку расширения открывается `popup` с `iframe` и `button`.
При нажатии на `button`, должен меняется `url` в `iframe`.

Проблема в том, что если открываю `popup.html` из папки на пк, все работает!! Но если запускаю через расширение, то при нажатии на `button` ничего не происходит.

Manifest:

```
{
"name": "fb-tab",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "my description",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png" ,
"default_popup" : "popup.html"
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id='click'>click me</button>

<iframe style="display:none" 
id='MainPopupIframe' src='url_2.html' 
width="500" height="650" /></iframe>
```

Js:

```
$(function(){
    $('#MainPopupIframe').load(function(){
    $(this).show();
    console.log('laod the iframe')
      });

    $('#click').on('click', function(){
    $('#MainPopupIframe').attr('src', 
   'url_2.html');    
     });
});
```

[Пример на jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/myproplata/q7vytj4m/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=q7vytj4m#&togetherjs=e3qhGuzvM1)

Comment: Поясните, что именно нужно. Я не понял.